# When will Compiler not create default constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor

I have in my book the following statement:

If we have given any constructor for a class whether it is

1. our own explcit default constructor ( i.e parameterless or with
parameters having default values )

or

2. our own constructor with parameters

Then compiler will not create implicit default constructor.

BUT I have doublt about point 2 and I suspect my book id either incorrect or outdated because my following code does have a constructor with parameters but the compiler is generating internal constructor too.

```
#include <iostream>

class imminent{
    public:
    imminent(int x, int y){
    std::cout << "I am explicit constructor" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    imminent gilfray(); /* compiler creates internal default constructor 
                           that why this line is compiled without errors*/

    imminent jimmy(1, 2);
}
```

Moreover, how can I put my c++ code in real way here as this time I was forced to use JS in the code snippet, isn't there any c++ code sharing option ?

Comment: Have a look at most vexing parse: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse. `imminent gilfray();` is a function returning `imminent`

Answer (score 0):

```
imminent gilfray();
```

I believe you intend this line to declare a variable `gilfray`, with type `imminent`.

However, it does not.
Instead, it declares a *function* `gilfray`, with no parameters, and a return type of `imminent`.

No default constructor is used in this code.

You can verify that `gilfray` is not a variable by trying to actually use it.

```
gilfray.DoSomething(); // Likely a linker error: "Undefined function gilfray."
```

---

If you wanted to try to use a default-constructor, it'd look like:

```
imminent gilfray; /* Create variable gilfray, with default ctor */
```

Comment: OMG! then it means I can't use gilfray to call data memebers of imminent(if it had) ?

Answer (score 0):

In C++03, in order to value-initialize an object, you need to use an equal sign:

```
imminent gilfray = imminent();
```

In C++11, `imminent gilfray()` still declares a function taking no parameters returning an `imminent`. However, you can use braces instead.

```
imminent gilfray{}; // compiler error
```